# Why is the razor syntax disrupting the css style?

Tags: html, css, razor, styles

In my asp.net mvc application layout i have css style just like picture below:
[image: Style Defined by CSS]

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 additional-nav">
   <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
      <li><a href="shop-account.html">My Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop-wishlist.html">My Wishlist</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
      <li><a href="page-login.html">Log In</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I added a form type of razor syntax but the style has been changed to following:
[image: Razor Syntax Styling]

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 additional-nav">
   <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
      <li><a href="shop-account.html">My Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop-wishlist.html">My Wishlist</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
      @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
      using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
      {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <li>
         @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
      }
      }
      else
      {
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
      }
   </ul>
</div>
```

What do you think is the problem?! how can i achieve the first design? any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a css expert but I think that this can be done by css.

in the form tag add style attribute like :

```
new { style="display: inline-flex;" }
```

Comment: You are a genius man :) Thanks for the to the point answer... Cheers +1

Comment: Never received sucha straight forward answer, Thank you again!

Comment: The problem with this is that you'll break html syntax rules. As @sLaks put it: "you can't stuff a `<form>` inside a `<ul>` tag".

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>` tags can only contain `<li>`s.

You can't stuff a `<form>` in the middle.

Comment: Put the `<form>` inside the `<li>`.

Comment: Sorry how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could left the `form` tag out of the `<ul>`: after all, you're firing the submit action of that form using Javascript. I.e.:

```
<!-- Logout Form -->
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }
}
<!-- Horizontal menu options -->
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 additional-nav">
   <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
      <li><a href="shop-account.html">My Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop-wishlist.html">My Wishlist</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop-checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
      @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
      <li>
         @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
      }
      else
      {
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
      }
   </ul>
</div>
```